# How to keep button enabled after closing the form

Tags: button, visual-studio-2012, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm trying to make a system and I'm having trouble with buttons being disabled.

I have a function that makes the button on a another form enable the button on the main form but whenever I get back to the main form the button becomes disabled again.

How do I keep this permanent even after closing the program? Can I save it in a database to keep its function enabled even if its default is disabled?

Here's the picture of what it looks like:

[image: Here's the picture of what it looks like]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Take two buttons - "button1" and "button2" on "MainForm" Form.

Set property Enabled=false for "button1"

### MainForm.cs

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 oFrm2 = new Form2();
        oFrm2.evtFrm += new ShowFrm(oFrm2_evtFrm);
        oFrm2.Show();
    }

    void oFrm2_evtFrm()
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Take one button - "button1" on "Form2" Form.

### Form2.cs

```
public delegate void ShowFrm();

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event ShowFrm evtFrm;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (evtFrm != null)
        {
            evtFrm();
        }
    }
}
```

- MainForm will display first.
- Click on "button2" to display "Form2".
- On "Form2", click on "button1" to make enable "button1" of "MainForm"
- If you want to make "button1" enable permanent, you have to store value - "button1" is enable or disable.